# Angular : $resource cache option does not cache

Tags: angularjs, caching, ngresource

I have a quite basic $resource call :

```
getActiveListUsers = function(departmentId){
    var activeUsersList = $resource("rest/users/active", {}, {
        'getActiveUsersList': {method: 'GET', isArray: true, cache : true}
    });

    return activeUsersList.getActiveUsersList(
                    {departmentId: departmentId}
    );
}
```

Though, when I look through network calls, I see that the same request is always called, and when I look at the 'cache' part of the request, I see it is fetched every time.

I am surely doing it the wrong way (or understanding it the wrong way!)... thus, any tip is welcomed here!

Thanks in advance!

Angular version : 1.2.16 (cannot be upgraded)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this article it might help you to use $resource cache in a much better manner...

http://blog.aliasapps.com/caching-get-requests-using-angular-resource/

Comment: Thanks for this link. Though, I already read it : it is one one of those I learned from. And I cannot see what I do wrong since this looks the exact same way Enventually, this tuto is not very "rich".